# How to find 90 degree angle in any polygon

Tags: algorithm, graphics, linear-algebra

I'm trying to programe agorythm in Java to find 90 degree angles in any polygon.

I have ArrayList of Points (double x, double y) representing a polygon.
Last point and first point are the same.

Result should be ArrayList containing these vertexes where is a 90 degree angle.

I was trying to figure something out by using Perpendicular Lines and calculate angle between them, but this didn't worked.

Do You have any idea how to do this?

And how to determine that i want to check angles from inside of polygon only?

If I have case like this:

[image]

I want only get green one 90 angles

Comment: Make use of the fact that the product of two orthogonal vectors vanishes to zero.

Comment: "this didn't worked": hard to believe, this *must* work. (Provided you use a tolerance as chances are high that the angles are never exactly 90°.)

Comment: Maybe try to post your code.

Comment: I have added exact picture what i mean by finding 90 angles

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Axel Kemper in a comment, you can make use of the fact that a dot product of two orthogonal (i.e. at 90 degrees to each other) vectors is 0.

```
// set tolerance to some small value to handle floating point errors
static final int TOLERANCE = 0.01; 
ArrayList<Point> find90degCorners(ArrayList<Point> points)
{
    ArrayList<Point> corners = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for(int i = 1; i < points.size() - 1; i++)
    {
         Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
         Point current = points.get(i);
         Point next = points.get(i + 1);

         // To get vector, subtract previous point from each point.
         //   vector A = next - current
         //   vector B = current - prev

         // Multiply element-wise for dot product A.B:
         double dotProduct = ((next.x - current.x) * (current.x - prev.x)) +
             ((next.y - current.y) * (current.y - prev.y));

         // normal of 2D vector is found by swapping x and y
         // and flipping sign of second component

         // to check whether it is an exterior or interior angle,
         // take the dot product of one vector with the
         // normal of the other
         double direction = ((next.x - current.x) * (current.y - prev.y)) +
             ((next.y - current.y) * (prev.x - current.x));

         // check if the product is within the tolerance of zero:
         if((dotProduct > -TOLERANCE) && (dotProduct < TOLERANCE) && (direction > 0.0))
         {
              corners.add(current);
         }
    }
    return corners;
}
```

You can discriminate between whether the interior or the exterior angle is 90 degrees by doing a second dot product with the vector normal and comparing to zero. Whether your test should be > 0 or < 0 depends on the polygon winding (clockwise or anti-clockwise) and the direction of the positive X and Y axes.

Comment: I have added exact picture what i mean by finding 90 angles

Comment: I updated my answer when I saw your picture. Try the code, if it doesn't work, try changing the (direction < 0) test to (direction > 0).